# Attribute extension in XSLT task doesn't work

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

Here is the problem:

I have an XSLT task that suppose to produce an XML file as output. This is the output I am currently getting:

> C:\Users\rmrd001\git\xslt-framework\examples\intermediate\odt-folder\t2\t2.1\content

It produces a file without any extension. So the windows doesn't provide default program to open with. Of course, desired result is same but with extension included. Namely:

> C:\Users\rmrd001\git\xslt-framework\examples\intermediate\odt-folder\t2\t2.1\content.xml

And here is the task definition:

```
<xslt in="@{file}" out="${dita-odt.path.odt-unzipped-base-dir}/${common-path}/${file-base-name}" style="${dita-odt.path.text-odt-xsl}" extension="xml" force="true">
                            <param name="dir-path-styles-xml" expression="${dita-odt.path.odt-unzipped-base-dir}/${common-path}"/>
                            <!--The following parameter is designated for reference nodes that require absolute path. For example draw:image/@href. This is to achieve system portability as well.-->
                            <param name="project-base-dir-absolute-path" expression="${base-dir-unix}"/>
                            <classpath location="${infrastructure-base-dir}/${dita-odt.text-odt-xsl.processor}"/>
                        </xslt>
```

I know this is not the complete script, but everything works fine except the extension missing for the output document. There is no `mapper` nested into the **XSL** task. I can also work around it by adding `.xml` to the path specified into the  `out` attribute like this `out="${dita-odt.path.odt-unzipped-base-dir}/${common-path}/${file-base-name}.xml"`. Anyway, why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

For `<xslt>`, the `extension` attribute is ignored if either:

- the `out` attribute is set
- or a `<mapper>` is nested under `<xslt>`

To have `<xslt>` output a file with a certain extension, either:

- provide the extension to `out`
- or add a `<mapper>` that appends the extension

Comment: actually both `out` and `in` must be set.  The manual has just been fixed and for the next version of Ant will say: Will be ignored if a nested `<mapper>` or both `in` and `out` have been specified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path. If ${file-base-name} does not contain ".xml" at the end, you have to specify it. It would help to see its definition.

The default output for XSLT is not XML, because XSLT can write any content.

Comment: In other targets I need `content` to have other extension for example .odt. That's why I have excluded its extension so I can later add desired one depend on target purpose. Furthermore the xslt task should not care what is the extension for the output files that is why the `extension` attribute is designated for?

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html the default value for extension is specified with a leading dot, does ".xml" work? It also says "Will be ignored if a nested <mapper> has been specified."

Comment: Tried with ".xml" doesn't work either. As you can see from my post, there isn't nested <mapper> element.